# No route matches [GET] "/reporting/from_perl/0" after upgrading to Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm upgrading a very old rails application step by step. At the moment I am stuck at Rails 3.1. I did all the relevant steps for upgrading. For now I don't want to use assets so I disabled it in config/application.rb.

As soon as a change the rails version in my Gemfile from 3.0.20 to 3.1.12 I get a no-route-matches error. I also changed all upgrading steps back to 3.0 to see which part causes the error but it happens only when I change the line in the Gemfile.

My routes.rb:

```
Wawi::Application.routes.draw do
match ":controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))"
end
```

Please tell me if you need more code.

---

rake routes:

/:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))

(and a warning: circular argument reference)

---

Maybe another useful hint: The action is part of the Application Controller.

Comment: ids in rails usually start from 1, not zero. Are you sure you have correct value in db?

Comment: Sorry, but I am relatively new to ruby/rails and inherited this project. As far as I can see, this is a method which redirects requests from the perl part to the ruby part. In this method it is checked if :id exists but it's not used. Where/How should there be a value in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague I found the solution:
In application_controller.rb `session :session_key => '...'` had to be changed to `Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] = '...'`.

Answer (score 0):

are you calling Object#to_i on your object inside your url helper? may be the object is nil and nil.to_i is always 0. And also note, rails primary id starts from 1.

So you should give a try with running rake routes:

```
ruby bundle exec rake routes
```

After running that command you should see your url list that are available based on your route file.

Comment: I added the output of rake routes above.